# Calculating portfolio allocation beta with different asset classes?

Tags: modeling, portfolio-management, risk-management, beta

I'd like to calculate portfolio allocation beta on a portfolio that has different asset classes.  The portfolio may be made up of:

```
Short term bond fund (with beta tied to Barclays U.S. Aggregate Bond Index)
Sector fund 1 (with beta tied to DOW)
SP500 fund (with beta tied to SP500 index)
```

I understand how to calculate portfolio beta if all assets are benchmarked off the same index but not when beta is heterogenous.  Can anyone provide a formula(s) of how it is calculate along with some simple examples?

Comment: $\beta$ is always measured against a specific target. That is, you can't claim to have a $\beta$ of $x$ and not specify what benchmark you're measuring against. So, what index do you want to compare your portfolio to? That's really the only question you need to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first restate the formula of the beta of a portfolio $P$ relative to a benchmark $B$:

$$\beta_P=\frac{Cov(r_P,r_B)}{Var(r_B)} $$

As chrisaycock said in his comment, the key thing to understand is that the beta is a statistical measure computed relative to a benchmark. Hence, I believe that the real question you should be asking is:

*Which benchmark should I choose to compute a $\beta$ for a global portfolio?*

There is no real answer to that question; it depends who you want to present it to and what you are trying to demonstrate. The easy (and naive) answer would be to use a global equity index such as MSCI World. I believe that it is better to look into a factor analysis where you estimate the sensitivity of your portfolio to different risk factors, as I discussed in this [post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/what-are-the-steps-to-perform-properly-a-risk-factor-analysis-on-a-portfolio).

The different factors you will choose will then be several indices of the different asset classes (MSCI  World, Bonds Global Aggregate, etc).

Comment: Thanks.  I plan to use this technique in Excel http://www.investopedia.com/articles/financial-theory/09/calculating-beta.asp#axzz1zy7Jz24A to calculate beta for each asset.  What is the suggested look back period?  I will need to manually paste in newer closing prices if I want the most current beta.  How often should that be done?

Comment: @4thSpace You still seem to be missing the point. Don't worry about computing $\beta$ just yet. Instead worry about deriving one or more appropriate indices. SRKX is suggesting that you use [factor analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) to determine what really drives your portfolio.

Comment: @4thSpace I want to second SRKX's answer and say that what you propose is misguided at best.  A multi-asset class portfolio will have multiple risk sources, and $\beta$ is an inappropriate measure.  SRKX is right to call what you propose naive.